# subclassing convenience construtctor

Tags: objective-c, convenience-methods

If I have a super class with a convenience constructor as follows (using ARC):

```
+(id)classA {
    ClassA *foo = [[ClassA alloc] init];

    return foo;
}
```

If I then subclass ClassA, with a class named ClassB, and I want to override the convenience constructor, is the following correct:

```
+(id)classB {
    ClassB *foo = [ClassA classA];

    return foo;
}
```

(Assume that I cannot call alloc and init on ClassB).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct, since that allocates, inits and returns a ClassA, not a ClassB. The only way to do this is not to use ClassA explicitly:

```
+ (id) classA
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

Of course, you could also use old-fashioned `new` for this:

```
ClassB *myB = [ClassB new];
```

FWIW, assuming I would want to do more than just allocate and init, and my class is named Gadget, then I would do something like:

```
+ (id) gadgetWithNumber: (int) num
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithNumber: num];
    // or without ARC:
    // return [[[self alloc] initWithNumber: num] autorelease];
}
```

Of course that assumes that there is an `initWithNumber:` method in my class.

Comment: How would you go about subclassing a UIButton. I've see a lot of people subclassing, and in the constructor they do something like `MyBtnClass *myBtn = [MyBtnClass buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`

Comment: OK, Objective-C will return the correct type if you call such a "constructor" on UIButton. But that works differently. See my edit.

Comment: @CRD: As I understood it, `[X new];` was the original way to create an object, but later on, it was decided that allocating and initializing were two distinct processes and thus the `[[X alloc] init];` idiom became prevalent.

Answer (score 3):

A class method is passed `self` just like an instance method, only in the case of a class method the value of `self` is an instance of `Class`. So change your `classA` method to:

```
+ (id) classA
{
   return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

(Which is just the definition of `new` you inherit from `NSObject`. The convention is `newX` returns a retained reference, while `classnameX` returns an autoreleased reference. Using ARC the difference is really moot, but I'd go with `newX` myself.)

Now if `ClassB` is a sub-class of `ClassA` then `[ClassB classA]` will invoke `classA` with `self` being `ClassB` and you will `alloc` and `init` a `ClassB` instance.